# Javascript function with 2 arguments

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function with 2 arguments (`price1`, `price2`), which should be added together and the result would be displayed in a text field after adding `Vat` to them.

Overall, I need to have 3 text fields: **price1**, **price2** and **results**. In addition, the **results** field should be calculated after pushing the button **calculate**.

So far, I've come up with a return function with `document.write`, but it obviously doesn't display any text fields, which looks like that:

```
function getTotalPrice(price1,price2,Vat)
{
  var sum=price1+priceb;
  var Vat=20;
  return ((sum*Vat)*100)/100;
}
document.write(getTotalPrice(4,3));
```

I have no clue how to create the button that could calculate `Vat` and display it in the third text box.

Comment: Why do you have a third (unused) `Vat` variable in the function parameters?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, indeed, this one is also not working.

Comment: @Oded, optional parameters are technically fine. My question is not just why it was unused, but why `Vat` was redeclared inside the function, as it will then never take on any value except 20.

Answer (score 3):

Buttons are created with the input tag. An example that does what you want:

```
<input type="text" id="price1">
<input type="text" id="price2">
<input type="text" id="results">
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateResults()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateResults() {
    var price1Box = document.getElementById('price1');
    var price2Box = document.getElementById('price2');
    var resultsBox = document.getElementById('results');
    resultsBox.value = getTotalPrice(price1Box.value, price2Box.value);
}
</script>
```

There are cleaner ways to do this, but this is the most practical and simplest. You'll need the fixes posted by Bryan if you want `getTotalPrice` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Issues:

1. `Vat` is unused as an argument, and even if it were used it would always be reinitialized in your code and assigned a value of 20.
2. `priceb` was a typo.

Beyond that the code doesn't seem to have any evident problems.

```
function getTotalPrice(price1, price2, vat) {
  vat = (vat === undefined? 20 : vat); // give vat a default value if empty
  return (price1 + price2) * vat;
}

document.write(getTotalPrice(4, 3));
```

**Edit:** Per the comment below, which is true, I figured I should just go ahead and simplify the math here. If the asker has a different equation in mind he should probably explain a bit more.

**Edit:** 
(vat === undefined? 20 : vat) is correct, producing any value other than *undefined*, default 20.
(vat === undefined? vat : 20) will only produce *undefined* or *20*.

Comment: Unless I'm particularly mistaken, no one seems to have noticed that ((sum * vat) * 100) / 100 == sum * vat. What I think was intended was (sum * ((100 + vat) / 100)).

Comment: @PAG, true. I simplified things above.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getTotalPrice(price1,price2)
  {
    var vat = 20;
    return (((price1+price2) * vat) * 100) / 100;
  }

  function calculate()
  {
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.value = getTotalPrice(document.getElementById('price1').value, document.getElementById('price2').value);
  }
</script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="price1" />
  <input type="text" id="price2" />
  <input type="text" id="result" />
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the typos anyway, I'm working on this code for some time (you're probably laughing now), and these bits are in the end the cleanest picture of what I am actually trying to do. Thank you very much again!